# How to create a column of row id in Spark dataframe for each distinct column value using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-data-factory

I have a data frame in scala spark as

category | score |

A   |       0.2

A   |       0.3

A   |       0.3

B    |      0.9

B    |      0.8

B     |     1

I would like to 
add a row id column as

category | score | row-id

A      |    0.2  |    0

A      |    0.3    |  1

A      |    0.3     | 2

B       |   0.9     | 0

B     |     0.8   |   1

B      |    1      |  2

Basically I want the row id to be monotonically increasing for each distinct value in column category. I already have a sorted dataframe so all the rows with same category are grouped together. However, I still don't know how to generate the row_id that restarts when a new category appears.  Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for [`Window`](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-functions-windows.html) aggregation functions

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number
import df.sparkSession.implicits._

val window = Window.partitionBy('category).orderBy('score)
df.withColumn("row-id", row_number.over(window))
```

Window functions work kind of like `groupBy` except that instead of each *group* returning a single value, each *row* in each group returns a single value. In this case the value is the row's position *within* the group of rows of the same category. Also, if this is the effect that you are trying to achieve, then you don't need to have pre-sorted the column `category` beforehand.